# how to exec a child process in different session on freebsd

Tags: linux, bash, freebsd

**i want to exec my child process in new session from the parent,on linux i could use bash command "setsid",but not able to find equivalent bash command  on freebsd** .

**parent script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
setsid exec $script
```

child script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while (1)
do
//some code//
done
```

this is the script i am trying to run:but it times out on freebsd as "setsid" command not found on freebsd but it works in linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `setsid` you are calling is not a bash command, but a [Linux one](https://linux.die.net/man/1/setsid).

FreeBSD doesn't have it in the base system, but it has [setsid(2) function](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=setsid&sektion=2), so you'd need to find an appropriate implementation of `setsid` program. You can try [this one](https://github.com/jerrykuch/ersatz-setsid).